# Why is there a node_modules folder under my home folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue-cli-3

I already have a global *node_modules* folder in */usr/local/lib/node_modules*, but I just found there is also a *~/node_modules* folder under my home folder. Can I delete this one?

I execute `node -e "console.log(global.module.paths)"`  and I get:

```
[ '/Users/Username/node_modules',
'/Users/node_modules',
 '/node_modules' ]
```

And if I delete the *node_modules* folder, which is under the home directory, then I execute `npm list @vue/cli-ui`. It would should this error:

```
/Users/Username
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY @vue/cli-ui@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: @vue/cli-ui@3.0.1, required by Username
```

So, can I delete the *node_modules* folder under my home directory? What's the use of it? Or should I need reinstall Node.js and npm?

And if I do delete this folder, when I execute `npm ls`, I would get these errors:

```
/Users/Username
├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY @vue/cli-ui@3.0.1
│ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY @akryum/winattr@3.0.0
│ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY fswin@2.17.1227
│ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY @vue/cli-shared-utils@3.0.1
│ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY chalk@2.4.1
│ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY execa@0.10.0
│ │ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY joi@13.6.0
│ │ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY hoek@5.0.4
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

Now everything is OK after executing `npm cache verify`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`module.paths` are the paths where Node.js search for NPM packages; and it actually **doesn't search** in your NPM global directory, as you can see.

More information is in *[Loading from the global folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)* and in *[All together...](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)*.

You see those paths because you're executing `node -e ...` when you are in  home directory, the Node.js simply traverse all `node_modules` paths to the root.

```
'/Users/node_modules',
 '/node_modules' ]
```

Relating to your question: Yes, you can delete `~/node_modules`; probably it's there because you **once** wrote `npm i MODULE` without `-g` flag and your current working directory was `~`.

Comment: I delete this folder and I get some errors and I update it on my question. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Delete the package.json in your home directory. He's reading that file and obviously he doesn't find anything because you just deleted the node_modules.

Comment: To deal with global modules, use `npm -g` (ex: `npm -g ls`)

Comment: The weired thing is that there is no package.json or package-lock.json file at my home folder. So I don’t know why it would show me these errors after I delete the node_modules folder.

Comment: What node version?

Comment: npm version is 5.6.0 and node version is 8.11.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184316/discussion-between-kopiro-and-t-t).

Answer (score 0):

After years of using node, I've idiotically installed it everywhere on my Windows machine.

- Delete all "path\to\node_modules" folder and the "path\to\node_modules\ ..\package.json". In other words, remove node_modules, package.json, yarn, etc that are located in weird places (credits to [kopiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497035/why-is-there-a-node-modules-folder-under-my-home-folder/78104150#comment93864740_53497491)).
- Make sure you only have one copy of node on your machine at a time.
- If you want multiple copies, I recommend to use NVM to manage multiple versions for node in both WSL and Windows. There will be less confusion.
- Chocolatey is very nice for installing cli apps like nvm
  https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/nvm

Good luck!